# Dynamic import in setup() VueJS 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to dynamically import a .json file in my Nuxt 3 project.
What I am trying to do:

The folder name "production" needs to be dynamic, the variable can also be "development" for example. So I put the name in a variable, and try to use that in the import() function.

```
export default {
  async setup() {
    const pathName = "production"
    const textOndersteTextArtikel = await import(`~/data/text/${pathName}/artikel.json`)

    return {
      textOndersteTextArtikel: textOndersteTextArtikel
    }
  },
```

But then I get this error:
[image: Error from console]

Also escaping the import with + signs doesn't work, and provide the same error.

```
const pathName = "production"
const textOndersteTextArtikel = await import("~/data/text/"+pathName+"/artikel.json")
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a json file, import a js file that exports a json:
create artikel.js and inside that put:

```
export default %your json%;
```